# Add conditionals to is.na

Tags: r, raster, na

I am pretty new to R and have been working on code to to compute linear regressions between NDVI and time for all the pixels in a 10 layer RasterStack (using the Raster package in R). I have this working, but I need to add some conditionals to my is.na statement to make sure that I only get outputs for pixels that have values in more than half (6+ out of 10) pixels and have at least one value in each "decade group". NA values in this case are due to cloud cover in certain areas of some of my rasters.

Here is where I am at currently...

```
#years variable
years <- c(1984, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1996, 2002, 2006, 2011, 2013, 2016)

#slope function
fun_slope <- function(y) { 
  if(all(is.na(y))) {
    NA
  } else {
    m = lm(y ~ years); summary(m)$coefficients[2] 
  }
}

fun_pvalue <- function(y) { 
  if(all(is.na(y))) {
    NA
  } else {
    m = lm(y ~ years); summary(m)$coefficients[8] 
  }
}

slope <- calc(NDVI4715_NA, fun_slope)
pvalue <- calc(NDVI4715_NA,fun_pvalue)
```

So as it stands, if all 10 years have an NDVI value of NA, then the resulting pixel in the output will be NA. I want to make it so that if half or more of the pixels in a single RasterStack pixel are NA then the output will be NA. I also want to group my years variable in these "decade groups":

1. 1984, 1990, 1991, 1992
2. 1996, 2002, 2006
3. 2011, 2013, 2016

And add a conditional that makes sure that each pixel has at least one NDVI value in each of the three groups. So if a pixel is missing all of the values in at least one of these groups then the output should be NA.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A bit closer, I think is `if(sum(is.na(y)) > 5)`

Comment: Ah okay that part worked! Would be > 4 in my case but thanks! So thats the first part solved.